# Not being able to run a java executable

Tags: java, openjdk, minecraft

I am currently trying to install forge (forge-1.18.2-40.0.36-installer.jar) on my new ubuntu 22.04 install. I have already installed minecraft (with the .deb), show the "secret" .minecraft folder and allowed the file to be executed. But can I try to execute it (either by double click or by right click and then execute) with OpenJDK java 11 Runtime, nothing happens, even in the system Monitor.

I hope you can help me with my problem and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that forge-whatever.jar is allowed to execute as a program. Do this by right clicking on it, selecting properties, going to permissions, and making sure the "Allow executing file as program" is checked.

Have you tried running it in a terminal? Navigate to where the .jar is located in nautilus (the file explorer), click on the 3 dots menu up top, and select "Open in terminal". To run it here, use

```
java -jar forge-1.18.2-40.0.36-installer.jar
```

Or whatever the .jar is called. I don't believe it needs root privileges, but if it gives you errors about "no permission" or something, try running it with "sudo" in front.

At the very least, running it in console will spit out more information.